# Unexpected token error on Anonymous window

Tags: apex, unexpectedexception

I am trying to create one custom list and trying to pass it to defined method via Anonymous window but it is giving me

> Line: 1, Column: 19 Unexpected token 'p'.

Helping me to fix this is much appreciated.

```
People_Tracing__c p=new People_Tracing__c(Person_1__c='a0U2w00000ExprwEAB',Person_2__c='a0U2w00000Exps2EAB',Contact_Date__c=2022-01-21);
List<People_Tracing__c> l=new list<People_Tracing__c>();
l.add(p);
List<People_Tracing__c> l1= CTPeopleTracingController.checkDuplicates(l);
System.debug(l1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler technically accepts YYYY-MM-dd as a date literal, but you can only use them in inline SOQL statements. Outside of that context, dates in Apex code must be constructed via Date.newInstance or another method:

```
People_Tracing__c p = new People_Tracing__c(Person_1__c='a0U2w00000ExprwEAB',
                                            Person_2__c='a0U2w00000Exps2EAB',
                                            Contact_Date__c=Date.newInstance(2022,1,21)); 
List<People_Tracing__c> l=new list<People_Tracing__c>(); 
l.add(p); 
List<People_Tracing__c> l1= CTPeopleTracingController.checkDuplicates(l); 
System.debug(l1);
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!!!